# Why is (void) 0 a no operation in C and C++?

Tags: c++, c, compiler-construction

I have seen debug printfs in *glibc* which internally is defined as `(void) 0`, if *NDEBUG* is defined. Likewise the [`__noop`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s6btaxcs%28VS.80%29.aspx) for Visual C++ compiler is there too. The former works on both GCC and VC++ compilers, while the latter only on VC++. Now we all know that both the above statements will be treated as no operation and no respective code will be generated; but here's where I've a doubt.

In case of `__noop`, MSDN says that it's a intrinsic function provided by the compiler. Coming to `(void) 0` ~ Why is it interpreted by the compilers as no op? Is it a tricky usage of the C language or does the standard say something about it explicity? Or even that is something to do with the compiler implementation?

Comment: By just giving `0;` as a statement, I don't get warnings or errors, and I am sure it'll not do any effictive operation and is equal to a no op; Even if so, why type cast it to void? Also, in case of the `#define dbgprintf (void) 0`, when it's called like `dbgprintf("Hello World!");` -> `(void) 0("Hello World!");` - what does it mean?

Comment: this should probably be `#define dbgprintf(x) (void)0;` though I found `#define dbgprintf(x)` perfectly sufficient. I think the cast to void is to remove any return value, so if it is used in context that requires value (and should not), it will cause an error/warning, instead of passing silently.

Comment: Yea, I didn't notice that the #define ignore param (x) and just does a `(void) 0`. Thanks for pointing it out :)

Comment: Well, imagine you are a compiler. What code would you generate for this statement:`(void) 0;`? Now you know.

Comment: @KubaOber: Haha.. true, I was asking more about the specifics on the typecast, in a language laweryese way ;)

Comment: Why not use ```#define dbgprintf ``` instead of ```#define dbgprintf ((void) 0)``` ??? @legends2k   Is there a reason?

Comment: @AntiMoron The question is more centered on what does `((void) 0)` mean. Not how to define a no-op macro.

Comment: Of course I know that. Just curious about. For ```(void)0``` needs more typing.

Comment: @SF. `#define dbgprintf(x)` is not sufficient, because macros may be used under bare `if` clause(without `{}`), i.e. `if (something) dbgprintf(...)`. Thus defining as such silently creates logical error in your code.

Comment: @imkzh True, albeit if it's code for my own consumption, not some sort of library, I tend not to duplicate security practices, of which one is "No bare if!" which can bite in way more cases than this. Albeit this one is especially insidious as the bug will strike only with debug off.

Comment: @SF. That is! I personally follow the "no bare if" rule, but I notice there are some popular(to my surprise, they are also large and modern) libraries using "bare if"s, so I decide to point out that `#define xxx` is not safe enough to remove them in production code.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

`(void)0` (+`;`) is a valid, but 'does-nothing' C++ expression, that's everything. It doesn't translate to the `no-op` instruction of the target architecture, it's just an empty statement as placeholder whenever the language expects a complete statement (for example as target for a jump label, or in the body of an `if` clause).

From [Chris Lutz's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2198950/why-is-void-0-a-no-operation-in-c-and-c#comment2148729_2198975):

It should be noted that, when used as a macro (say, `#define noop ((void)0)`), the `(void)` prevents it from being accidentally used as a value (like in `int x = noop;`).

For the above expression the compiler will rightly flag it as an invalid operation. GCC spits `error: void value not ignored as it ought to be` and VC++ barks `'void' illegal with all types`.

Comment: Thanks Chris, for clarifying regarding why the type cast to void is made; it prevents from accidental usage of the said noop exp. in expression like assignment, now I did understand.

Comment: Can we say that, it's like "pass" in Python?

Comment: @UnhandledException Yes, it is!

Comment: I have an issue with this `(void)(0)` I am actually trying to do `(void)(0) += 1` and returning it the value updated that it `1`. But I get `0` as a result ?

Answer (score 12):

Any expression that doesn't have any side-effects can be treated as a no-op by the compiler, which dosn't have to generate any code for it (though it may). It so happens that casting and then not using the result of the cast is easy for the compiler (and humans) to see as not having side-effects.

Answer (score 4):

I think you are talking about [glibc](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/), not [glib](http://library.gnome.org/devel/glib/), and the macro in question is the `assert` macro:

In glibc's `<assert.h>`, with `NDEBUG` (no debugging) defined, `assert` is defined as:

```
#ifdef NDEBUG
#if defined __cplusplus && __GNUC_PREREQ (2,95)
# define __ASSERT_VOID_CAST static_cast<void>
#else
# define __ASSERT_VOID_CAST (void)
#endif
# define assert(expr)           (__ASSERT_VOID_CAST (0))
#else
/* more code */
#endif
```

which basically means `assert(whatever);` is equivalent to `((void)(0));`, and does nothing.

From the C89 standard (section 4.2):

> The header `<assert.h>` defines the `assert` macro and refers to another macro,
>
> ```
> NDEBUG
> ```
>
> which is not defined by `<assert.h>`.  If `NDEBUG` is defined as a macro name at the point in the source file where `<assert.h>` is included, the `assert` macro is defined simply as
>
> ```
> #define assert(ignore) ((void)0)
> ```

I don't think defining a debug print macro to be equal to `(void)0` makes much sense.  Can you show us where that is done?

Comment: Yeah, it's glibc and not glib, thanks for notifying; corrected it in the question.

Comment: http://doc.ddart.net/msdn/header/include/assert.h.html - This is one of the many *assert.h*s  I've seen with `(void) 0`.

Comment: @legends2k: `assert(expr);` is not a debug printing macro.  My answer above answers your question about `assert()`.

Comment: I agree, it's assert. But the whole doubt was to know more about the `(void) 0` in general as no operation, based on the language or compiler constructs. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> Even if so, why type cast it to void? Also, in case of the #define dbgprintf (void) 0, when it's called like `dbgprintf("Hello World!"); -> (void) 0("Hello World!");` - what does it mean?

Macros replace your code with something else, so if you #defined dbgprint (that accepts x) as

```
void (0)
```

then no rewriting of X will occur in replacement, so `dbgprintf("Helloworld")` will not be converted to `(void) 0("Hello world")`, but to `(void) 0;` - not only macro name dbgprint is replaced by `(void) 0`, but the whole call `dbgprintf("...")`

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, I try some code like this in Main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#define TRACE ((void)0)
int main() {
  TRACE("joke");
  std::cout << "ok" << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Then, I build the Release version exe file with Main.i output. In Main.i file, the TRACE macro was replaced to:`((void)0)("joke")`, and visual studio give an warning:"warning C4353: nonstandard extension used: constant 0 as function expression.

Use '__noop' function intrinsic instead".

Run the exe file, console print out "ok" characters.

So I think all is clear: the definition of macro TRACE[#define TRACE ((void)0)] is illegal according to c++ syntax, but c++ compiler of visual studio supports this behavior as a compiler extension.

So my conclusion is: [#define TRACE ((void)0)] is illegal c++ statement, and you at best DO NOT use this. But [#define TRACE(x) ((void)0)] is legal statement. That's all.