# what is the usage of `(void)d`

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the purpose of the statement “(void)c;”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6145548/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-statement-voidc)

```
class ArgString : public Arg::Base
{
public:
    ...
    bool CanConvertToInt() const
    {
        const char *cstr = mValue.c_str();
        char *result = 0;
        long d = strtol(cstr, &result, 10);
        (void) d; // what is the usage of this line?
        return result != cstr;
    }

private:
    std::string mValue;
};
```

Can someone tell me what the purpose of the following line is?

```
(void) d;
```

Thank you

// Update //

As some people pointed out, the purpose of the line is to suppress the compilation warning. To me, that is very strange. Because this is much severe warning

```
    warning C4996: 'sprintf': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using sprintf_s instead. To disable deprecation, use
_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.
```

Why we ignore this big warning and ONLY address the smaller one.

Comment: I dont know what the purpose is, but it IMHO the statement doesnt produce any effects ;-)

Comment: Note this is code you have control over, please comment the answer after it.

Comment: The warning about `sprintf` is issued by a Microsoft compiler.  `sprintf` is a standard C function, and it can be used safely if you're careful.  But that's a separate question; there was no `sprintf` call in the code you showed us.

Comment: The warning about `sprintf` just appeared within the last couple of years, the code in question was probably older than that and did not generate a warning until you upgraded your compiler. It's a good idea to eliminate all warnings so that when a new one appears, you'll notice it and take action.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The pattern `(void)d` is typically done to tell a code analyzer that you are explicitly ignoring the return value of a function.  Many C analyzers consider it an error to ignore a return value as it could result in ignoring a failure.  This is a way of saying "I meant to do that"

Answer (score 3):

The only time I've seen something like that is to prevent a warning about an unused variable. Casting something to `(void)` does absolutely nothing, but it counts as a usage of the variable.

Comment: Right it doesnt even invoke a `operator void` even tho gcc does so incorrectly

Answer (score 1):

It avoids an unused variable warning. I've seen this used in assert macros so that in release you don't get unused variable warnings. It evaluates to a no-op.