# Why does (void)0 stop "statement has no effect" warnings?

Tags: c, macros

I have a `trace()` macro I turn on and off with another macro, e.g.

```
#ifdef TRACE
    #define trace(x) trace_val(x, 0)
#else
    #define trace(x) 0
#endif
```

This generates `warning: statement with no effect` from gcc when I call `trace()` with `TRACE` undefined. After a little searching I found that changing

```
#define trace(x) 0
```

to

```
#define trace(x) (void)0
```

silences the error. My question is: Why? What's the difference?

Comment: Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2198950/why-is-void-0-a-no-operation-in-c-and-c

Comment: @OrgnlDave That question doesn't go into why (void)0 is different to just 0.

Comment: I suppose it doesn't explicitly. If you read into it it does. Too late to delete my comment but don't worry it wasn't a vote to close the question

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The cast to void makes it clear that the programmer intends to throw the result away. The purpose of the warning is to indicate at that it's not obvious that the statement has no effect and thus it's useful to alert the programmer to that in case it was unintentional. A warning here would serve no purpose.

Comment: That makes some sense. Is this a documented part of the language syntax?

Comment: It's less about the language syntax than the particular compiler.  Warnings aren't stipulated in the language, they're extras the compiler does to make things a bit easier for you.  With or without the compier's warning, both syntaxes in the code are valid at the language level; they mean essentially the same thing, it's just that in one case it's more "obvious" (in a very informal sense) that it's intentional.

Comment: _This_ warning isn't stipulated in the language. Some warnings are, but those are of the kind "this officially is an error, but I'll let it slip".

Answer (score 7):

The warning and the workaround are compiler-specific. What you can do however is the following:

```
#define NOP do { } while(0)

#ifdef ENABLE_TRACE
    #define TRACE(x) trace_val(x, 0)
#else
    #define TRACE(x) NOP
#endif
```

This avoids the underlying problem in the first place.

Comment: Will the `{}` cause a problem with trailing semicolons?  `trace(x); trace(y);` will end up looking like `{}; {};`...

Comment: @cHao: That's not the problem. It's `if (foo) trace(x); else trace(y);` The `{};` will end the `if` leaving the `else` hanging.

Comment: That will leave `x` unused though, causing warnings if that's the only use of `x`. I like: `((void) (false && (x)))`

Comment: @David: Clever. Why the void cast?

Comment: To avoid the very warning the OP was asking about. ;) The `false` avoids evaluating `x`, assuming that's what's desired. (Your solution works too. In fact, I think I like it better.)

Comment: @David: Ah, I was thinking about putting it inside the `while` condition. Would you like to remove your downvote?

Comment: @David: I rethought this and came to the conclusion that if the `trace` macro is the only use of a variable, the warning is actually sensible and should not be surpressed. After all, what sense would it make to output the value of an unused variable?

Comment: @Orgnl: That however poses the problem that it doesn't enfore the closing semicolon... Can you give an example where the `do/while` would have a different impact on the balancing then the function call `trace_val(x, 0)`?

Comment: @Orgnl: Obviously the downside is that "historically some C++ compilers have refused to inline-expand any function containing a loop." As you noted, these times have passed. BTW, you can actually remove comments on SO :)

Comment: Thanks about deleting comments, haha. This is what I get for reading/doing SO late at night. (By the way, I do have to compile with legacy compilers in one project I help maintain, so the habit of using if still works well for me). Argh, just posted this as an answer, I need to sleep.

Comment: @NiklasB. Actually, there is ONE advantage to the if () way of doing things. You can use single definitions. #define DO_IT 0   #define mymacro(x) if (DO_IT) x = 4; else (void)0 this way you can turn it on and off without a multi-line #ifdef thingy

Comment: I started to think that OP solution is best. Because `(void)0` you can place into expression itself and `do { } while(0)` you can not. For example- `(3,(void)0,7)` expression is perfectly valid, but `(3,do { } while(0),7)` it is not. Of course it is another question is it reasonable to put trace() calls into expressions itself. But for me `(void)0` wins :-)

Comment: @0x69: There are two problems with `(void)0`. One is that complete garbage will compile, leading to a round of bugfixing each time you enable tracing. (If you remove/change a variable, you may not notice the trace step, so the tracing code can easily slip out of sync from the other code.) The other is that you'll get bogus "... is unused" warnings if you compute/save a value just for tracing. That's not terribly uncommon, IMO.

Comment: For dismissing "is unused" warnings we can declare NOP trace part like this: `TRACE(x) (void)x`