# What does this expression mean, and why does it compile?

Tags: c, visual-c++

After a typo, the following expression (simplified) compiled and executed:

```
if((1 == 2) || 0 (-4 > 2))
  printf("Hello");
```

of course, the 0 shouldn't be there.

Why does it compile, and what does the expression mean?

The original (simplified) should look like this:

```
if((1 == 2) || (-4 > 2))
  printf("Hello");
```

none of this does compile:

```
if((1 == 2) || true (-4 > 2))
  printf("Hello");

if((1 == 2) || 1 (-4 > 2))
  printf("Hello");

if((1 == 2) || null (-4 > 2))
  printf("Hello");
```

Comment: I've just tried this and got [warning C4353](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2a68558f.aspx): "nonstandard extension used: constant 0 as function expression.  Use '__noop' function intrinsic instead"

Comment: i got `error: called object ‘0’ is not a function`

Comment: This has already been answered at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2198950/why-is-void-0-a-no-operation-in-c-and-c

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In fact it is **Microsoft specific**.

For debug purpose, you can use [`__noop`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s6btaxcs(v=vs.71).aspx) intrinsic, it specifies that the function and the parameters will no be evaluated.

In your case, Microsoft compiler thinks you are trying to use 0 to do the same, that's why it works but for example, on VS2012 it gives the warning :

```
warning C4353: nonstandard extension used: constant 0 as function expression.  Use '__noop' function intrinsic instead.
```

See this for more informations : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2a68558f(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: The important thing is, that the parameters don't get evaluated as well.

Comment: What does such noop-ed function return? `if((1 == 2) || 0 (-4 > 2))` requests a boolean. Is it some random number from a register?

Answer (score 26):

It looks like this is a Visual C++ extension to support a particular 'no function defined' idiom. From the [warning C4353](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2a68558f.aspx) page:

```
// C4353.cpp
// compile with: /W1
void MyPrintf(void){};
#define X 0
#if X
   #define DBPRINT MyPrint
#else
   #define DBPRINT 0   // C4353 expected
#endif
int main(){
    DBPRINT();
}
```

the intention being that `DBPRINT` is a no-op. The warning suggests `#define DBPRINT __noop` instead, using VC's [__noop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s6btaxcs.aspx) extension instead.

If you view the assembly listing for your output you'll see the second clause is omitted, even in debug mode.

Answer (score 14):

Guess it was interpreted as

```
if((1 == 2) || NULL (-4 > 2))
  printf("Hello");
```

where NULL is a function-pointer, by default returning int... What at actually happens in runtime is platform-dependent

Comment: The importance of type-safety... C++11 renders things more secure with this kind of problems by introducing another type of NULL value

Answer (score 9):

Visual Studio 2012 gives you the following warning:

warning C4353: nonstandard extension used: constant 0 as function expression.  Use '__noop' function intrinsic instead

it is a non-standard way to insert a "no operation" assembler instruction at that point of expression evaluation

Answer (score 1):

In ubuntu it is showing error

```
int main()
{
 if((1 == 2) || 0 (-4 > 2))
      printf("Hello");
}
```

o/p

```
niew1.c:3:19: error: called object â0â is not a function
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably `0` is casted to a function pointer here. Explicit cast may look like this:

```
if((1 == 2) || ((int (*)(int)) 0) (-4 > 2)) 
      printf("Hello");
```

However, I have no guesses about what function `0` is casted to in implicitly in your example.