# How to write a "dummy" (do nothing) line in C

Tags: objective-c, c

Is there a dedicated way to write a dummy line in C? (kind of like `pass` in Python) If you are wondering why I don't just leave a blank line, I need something that I can attach an Xcode breakpoint to-- if there is nothing there the breakpoint will skip to the next line!! So far I've been using `sleep(0)` for this purpose. I was wondering if there was a better/more efficient/more official way to accomplish this.

Oh, and I'm using Objective-C, so if there is anything that was added in Obj-C that fits this purpose, feel free to include it.

Comment: that's a c# statement...

Comment: Why do you need to make an Xcode breakpoint on an empty line, anyway?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add a trivial assignment

```
var = var;
```

Comment: This isn't completely trivial.

Comment: I am not understanding the keyword `var` in C.

Comment: @WhyWhat they're just using it as an example, substitute any variable in your program

Answer (score 25):

Put a semi colon. It works in C and Obj-C (and Java, and Swift, and many other languages).

```
;
```

Comment: I thought this would work, but putting a breakpoint in this line causes XCode to stop at the next line.

Answer (score 9):

`sleep(0)` works, so does a null statement (just a semicolon `;` on a single line) and the statement `i+1;`

Compiler optimization will usually result in no machine code being generated for these statements.

Comment: `sleep(0)` requires an #include and that #include is OS-dependent, right? The `;` solution sounds better

Answer (score 5):

Most of the answers already posted will do what you want, but if you need a block, try a pair of braces:

```
{}
```

And, if you need an actual statement that actually does nothing, and yet will survive compilation, then a little inline assembly can do the trick:

```
asm("nop");
```

Technically this isn't portable; but the `nop` instruction exists in basically [any instruction set you care to name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NOP_(code)#Machine_language_instructions). Also guaranteed* not to be compiled out!

Answer (score 3):

The good old [`(void)0`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2198975/3052438) should do it.

```cpp
(void)0;
```

`(void)` tells the compiler to just ignore the following number `0`.

Answer (score 2):

Just put the breakpoint on the first line you don't want executed.  The breakpoint stops the execution before the code on that line is executed.

---

Without creating a "fake" line:

```
    someMethod();
    // empty line
BREAKPOINT
    someOtherMethod();
```

With creating a "fake" line:

```
    someMethod();
BREAKPOINT
    ;
    someOtherMethod();
```

Both of these result in the exact same result.  The breakpoint stops at the same place.

Comment: That's the issue- the code sets a variable to a certain type so I can see it in the debugger, but on the next line it falls out of scope- as it should, I only have that in there for debugging.

Comment: @PopKernel Is that because you did not use braces for your if/loop? You can set the breakpoint on the closing brace.

Comment: Then move the breakpoint up a line.  If you are stepping through, there will be a line after the variable is set and before it falls out of scope.

Answer (score 1):

just place this constant:

```
0xDEBAF;
```

Comment: Please explain your answer. Now it is not very helpful.

Comment: Stefan it just  expresion  number in hex with view as normal english word like 0xdeadbeef https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexspeak

Answer (score 0):

What about "YES"
This is what I use when I wan't to switch off logs

`#define Log(s,...) YES`

Answer (score 0):

My compiler optimizes away statements like

```
(void)0;
;
0xDEBAF;
```

so it's impossible to put a breakpoint on those statements.

What it doesn't optimize away is statements like:

```
volatile int g_break;
int myFunction(void) {
  // Break on this line
  (void)g_break;
}
```

and

```
int myFunction(void) {
  // Break on this line
  volatile int xyz = 0;
}
```

where you can put a breakpoint on the line of code inside the function.